# How to avoid white flash when initializing QWebEngineView?

Tags: python, pyqt6, qwebengineview

I have a QWebEngineView that is populated when my application is initialized.
The first time `setHtml` is called, the whole application flashes white, not just the area of the QWebEngineView.
I tried to delay calling `setHtml` as long as possible but there is other code which has to be executed afterwards causing the flash to last a few seconds.
The white color is particularly unpleasant when the application is in dark mode.
The example below should allow to reproduce the effect when clicking the button.
Note that when clicking the button for the second time, the flash is limited to the QWebEngineView area as expected.

Is there a way to avoid updating the GUI until after the QWebEngineView is initialized, or at least change the color seen during the update?

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QPushButton
from PyQt6 import QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 400)
        self.setStyleSheet('background:gray')
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Status Bar Message disappears while initializing first webEngineView")   
        self.lay = QVBoxLayout()       
        w = QWidget()
        w.setLayout(self.lay)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)
        self.b = QPushButton('Add webEngineView')
        self.b.setStyleSheet('background:black;color:white')
        self.b.clicked.connect(self.load)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.b)          
        
    def load(self):
        self.webEngineView = QWebEngineView(parent=self)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.webEngineView)        
        # self.setUpdatesEnabled(False) # does not help
        self.webEngineView.setHtml("<style> body { background-color: black; color: white; } </style> <h1>Heading</h1> <p>Paragraph</p>") 
        # QApplication.processEvents() # reduces flash duration in this example but not in the full application
        time.sleep(1) # represents other code for GUI initialization
        # self.setUpdatesEnabled(True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: There's probably nothing you can do about it, it probably is required by the change in widget rendering which "switches" to GL compatibility mode. And, obviously, you have no control over the color, it's probably a default "flush" color of the OS or graphics drivers. What you could try, though, is to add the view since the very beginning of the window creation (as its own child!) and immediately hide it, then only show it when necessary.

Comment: thank you @musicamante! I have added `dummy = QWebEngineView(parent=self); dummy.setHtml('dummy');dummy.deleteLater()` to the start of my app and trigger the rest of the initialization with a timer. No flash anymore.